# Cant able to type in a textbox inside a ModalPopupExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a Multi-line text box inside a ModalPopupExtender , on opening the popup for the first time i cant able to type anything, if i click out side the container of the text box or reopening the modalpopup i can able to type.. This issue arises only in IE9 browser. in other browsers it works cool. Help! me in arriving to a solution.

Comment: any JS console error log? Please show basic code to help diagnose the problem

Comment: how are you opening the dialog box? did you check after setting focus on the textbox immidiately before/after opening it?

Comment: No am not getting any js Console error. Its working fine, i have a prob in IE 9 only..

Comment: i have tried setting the focus both in client and server side,     (Page.Form.DefaultFocus = ttName.ClientID)... but no use.

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
  <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="todoext" runat="server" CancelControlID="" DropShadow="True" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="samp" TargetControlID="LinkButton1">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="samp">
  <table>
 <tr>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </asp:Panel>
These are the snippets..

Answer (score 0):

in this i have used a tiny mce scripting in my code, in that

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
```

Due to this i have in-occurred through this error. After removing these lines, it worked fine.